# Is there a GUI linux application that shows per mounted disk i/o transfer rate in a graphic?

Tags: disk, monitoring, io, gui, software-rec

**Is there a GUI linux application that shows per mounted disk i/o transfer rate in a graphic?**

*(Like [gnome-system-monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/?c=140202) do for the swap mount but for each mounted drive)*

I'm looking for an application that works specificaly only on drives mounted on boot or USB drives connected. Not on iso images and other simillar mounts, since those are readed on a disk containing it.

What should be shown:

- i/o transfer rates of fstab mounts at boot
- i/o transfer rates of hardware drives connected (like an USB stick)

I know about [iotop](https://www.tecmint.com/iotop-monitor-linux-disk-io-activity-per-process/)-like software to **show it into the therminal**, but **it's not what I'm looking for**.
The best solution to me, would be that gnome-system-monitor automaticaly add those views under the resource tab. ([Post on https://extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/?c=140253))

I would like to see something like this (edited of gnome-system-monitor screenshot with Gimp), but where every collor reports the activity of a drive mounted:
[image: color for each mount]

Since the gnome-system-monitor already shows the swap mount in a graphic with the RAM usage, I thought I could find a plugin or setting that does show this for the drives mounted. But I can't find any.

But if there's an application that does it this way and could replace it. why not?

I've tried [Stacer](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer), but it doesn't give per disk i/o. So it's not what I'm looking for either.

I'm also using webmin, that has the same problem as Stacer, it show only a general i/o graphic. It's not per disk mount.
[image: webmin stats]

I've found one that should do the trick, but when I look the results it shows all the mounts instead of only physicaly present volumes.
It's an applet of Cinnamon Spicies: [Disk Utilization (ioDisk@ctrlesc)](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/161)

Here is a screenshot of it:
[image: Cinnamon applet]

You can see it also shows the loop mounts what shouldn't be. I can presume it will also show iso mounts and it doesn't show it into a graphic. So it's no solution yet.

Here's my system information:

- Linux Mint 21 Vanessa (x86-64) (Ubuntu 22.04 server install)
- Cinnamon version: 5.4.12       (Mint PPA source)
- Linux kernel: 6.1.8-060108-generic (Last version from official Ubuntu repo)

Comment: I've written this for myself but it runs on console: https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/watch_raw_io

Comment: When I ran it I got this: 
`raw_io.sh: 20: shopt: not found`
`raw_io.sh: 48: declare: not found`
`raw_io.sh: 61: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: What are the prerequisites for this script to run? @Artem S. Tashkinov

Comment: A recent version of bash and the Linux kernel. Looks like your OS is not Linux :-( What you're running doesn't look like Bash (Bourne Shell) at all. `shopt` built-in was introduced in Bash 2.0, in 1996 (!)

Comment: This `shopt --help` gave me : `shopt: shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]  Set and unset shell options.` So I presume it's due to else. I'm on Ubuntu server 22.04 installed with Cinnamon from the mint PPA. @Artem S. Tashkinov

Comment: I launched it the wrong way. I had to make it executable and double-click on it, but I used the sh command. That's why I got the error. @Artem S. Tashkinov

Comment: It's not graphic/no gui, though ... I wonder if this could be used to build a plugin for webmin or gnome-system-monitor in the resources tab. But I'm so far to have the knowledge to do so ... @Artem S. Tashkinov

Comment: Excellent :-) Glad it worked. Sorry, I only program in Bash and rarely in PHP. UI programs require a lot more.