# What's the difference between "sh command" and run as executable?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I used a script suggested by @Artem S. Tashkinov :"[I've written this for myself but it runs on console.](https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/watch_raw_io)"

*[See related post here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733075/is-there-a-gui-linux-application-that-shows-per-mounted-disk-i-o-transfer-rate-i)*

```
$sh raw_io.sh: 
20: shopt: not found 
raw_io.sh: 
48: declare: not found 
raw_io.sh: 
61: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

I found out I just had to make it executable and double-click on it, then "Run in terminal":

Since it is refreshing, I can't copy/paste the output. So I made a screenshot instead:
[image: output Run in terminal]

Since it works from a double-click, but I need to click on "Run in terminal", I was also wondering how to launch it direcly from the terminal.

```
~/Desktop$ raw_io
raw_iso: command not found
```

**So what's the difference between these ways of launching this?**

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /bin/sh`? I assume that has a symlink to `dash` (another shell)

Comment: for the first part, see [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/170373). For the second, if the program isn't in a directory in `PATH`, you need to give the path explicitly, e.g. `./raw_io`.

Comment: This script takes a single argument, refresh interval. Run it as `./raw_io 10` and you'll have ample time to copy its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you execute a script called `myscript`?

```
sh myscript        # Or sh /path/to/myscript
bash myscript      # Or bash /path/to/myscript
perl myscript      # Or perl /path/to/myscript
python myscript    # Or python /path/to/myscript
```

etc.

This is easy but you do need to know which interpreter to use to run the script, and as you have noticed trying to use the wrong one will generate errors (for example using `sh` instead of `bash`).

Better, is to let the script declare the correct interpreter itself. This is defined using the `#!` on the first line. For example this line would declare `bash` (specifically `/bin/bash`) as the interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

To use this feature you need to make the script executable,

```
chmod a+x myscript
```

and then provided it is in one of the list of colon-separated directories specified in `$PATH` you can run it exactly like any other program - with just its name

```
myscript
```

However, notice that the current directory (notated as `.`) is not in `$PATH` so if you're working on a script in the current directory, you will need to provide a path to the script so that it can be found. Here the `.` represents *current directory* and it's a path relative to your current working directory (i.e. the same place):

```
./myscript    # Or /full/path/to/myscript
```

There are good reasons why `.` is not usually in the `$PATH`, but if you must add it then put it at the end of the `$PATH` rather than the beginning. (See [History of UNIX not including current directory in $PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254711/100397) and [Why is . not in the path by default?](https://superuser.com/q/156582/332907).)

Notice that the script name or extension does not matter (unless you end up using a command name such as `test` that's already present in the system directories listed in `$PATH`). I've used `myscript` as the example here. You could use `myscript.sh` if you wanted, or even `confusion.png`, but you don't use `ls.exe` so I don't see a need to have `myscript.sh`. Be aware, though, that some GUIs may use file extensions to guess what's in the file and using extensions in a nonstandard way (such as `png` for a script) may confuse them. The proper way for a GUI to identify file contents would be to use an equivalent to the `file` command, but not all of them do that:

```
file myscript
```

Finally, when I've finished working on a script I'm going to reuse I tend to put it into a directory that is included in my `$PATH`. It then becomes a tool as easy to access as `ls` or `cp`. In my case I use `$HOME/bin` but you can choose any directory you like as long as it's listed in `$PATH`.